# Find a user universally

Tags: botframework

The "Collecting Input" demo bot saves a user name in `session.userData.name`. How can I search all of the users that have used the bot by name?

I need a function like

```
function findUser(nameQuery){
   ...
   return userData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more BotBuilder experience, I believe that this is entirely up to the host app. I am now working on a database to CRUD and query the users.